# React JSX file giving error "Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs

I have a file test_stuff.js that I am running with `npm test`

It pretty much looks like this:

```
import { assert } from 'assert';
import { MyProvider } from '../src/index';
import { React } from 'react';

const myProvider = (
  <MyProvider>
  </MyProvider>
);

describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, I get the error

```
/Users/me/projects/myproj/test/test_stuff.js:11
var myProvider = _react.React.createElement(_index.MyProvider, null);
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/projects/myproj/test/test_stuff.js:7:7)
```

What does that mean? I am importing React from 'react' successfully, so why would React be undefined? It is _react.React, whatever that means...

Answer (score 286, accepted):

To import React do `import React from 'react'` You add brackets when the thing you are importing is not the default export in that module or file. In case of react, it's the default export.

This might apply to your other imports depending on how you defined them.

Comment: I'm not sure why just yet but for me it was `import * as React from "react"`

Comment: Technically speaking, `import React from 'react'` is not valid since React is not the default export but it works due to using ES6 in conjunction with babel. Maybe your babel configuration are different forcing you to use the correct valid syntax which is `import * as React from 'react'`. For more info: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/5128

Comment: Another important thing I forgot to mention is that JSX require React to be in scope to work. However, you don't really need React besides Component and maybe other named exports. Maybe in the future you won't be importing React.

Comment: I'm using react-native with expo and my babel preset is `babel-preset-expo` https://github.com/expo/babel-preset-expo/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @Clintm as a test you could add `babel-preset-es2015` to your presets and change import statement to `import React from 'react'`. You can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015

Comment: If using typescript, the import style will also be affected by the setting of `esModuleInterop` in the tsconfig. The tsconfig must apply to the test files (check `include` and `files`).

Comment: very so nice answer

Comment: @FranjoPintarić  it was because I was using TypeScript

Comment: @Clintm you can also have a look at a similar question here if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325877/if-react-is-the-default-export-from-react-why-cant-we-use-some-other-name

Comment: Running into the same issue, and having `import * as React from "react"` solving it, but not wanting to change the entire code base, adding `"esModuleInterop": true` to `tsconfig.json` solved the issue as per comment here from @Matthias.

More details on that option on question [56238356](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)

Answer (score 57):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

This worked for me. I'm not sure why it fixed my version of this issue, though. So if you are someone who stumbled upon this problem and you use create-react-app as your starting boilerplate, this way of importing React will do the trick. (as of Oct '18, lol)

Comment: This was the issue I was having, when trying to import memo, useEffect, useState, in addition to react. Originally saw error "Cannot read property 'memo' of undefined", but this fixed it

Comment: This fixed it for me too (although instead of Component I import useState). I'm now very curious on the difference with my original, faulty `import { React, useState } from 'react'`;

Comment: @JosFabre it was faulty because `'react'` does not export `React` as non default per sé. However it `export useState`, `export Component`, etc.

Answer (score 38):

For those who are working ReactJS with TypeScript.

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Comment: This was my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Why is this necessary? I get this error all over my codebase when running jest.

Comment: There is a way to make import "beautiful again". Add "esModuleInterop: true" to your tsconfig.json. And enjoy your "import React from 'react'"! – Shulyk Volodymyr

Comment: it helps a lot , yes

Answer (score 13):

This error occured to me due to carelessness. It's actually

```
import React from 'react';
```

Brackets are for named exports such as this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
```

Answer (score 8):

This issue occurred while importing React from react, I placed it inside curly brackets.

Please do this:

`import React, {useState} from "react";`

Instead of:

`import  {React, useState} from "react";`

Answer (score 3):

I got this when trying to mock a component when unit testing but was not setting it up correctly

What I was doing that caused the error:

```
jest.mock("./SomeComponent", () => {
    return <div>MockSomeComponent</div>
});
```

What I needed to do:

```
jest.mock("./SomeComponent", () => {
    return () => <div>MockSomeComponent</div>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use destructor for importing the React object may cause you problems like this `import {React} from 'react';`.
This might be the cause of the error 90% of the time running this code above.

rather use:
`import React from 'react';`

And then you can access any member of the React class via:
**React.**

Answer (score 0):

Change:
**import { React } from 'react'**  to  **import React from 'react'**
Because React is a default export and you don’t need curly braces for any default exports.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you need to import multiple classes from 'react', you can have an alias for them except React. Something like,

```
import React, * as react from 'react';
```

Answer (score 0):

`React` is exported by default in that module, no need  {}.

Answer (score -1):

This error can be occured due to carelessness. Please add

```
import React from 'react'
```

It will be resolved after that