# Why am I getting "mongoose.connect is not a function" when trying to connect with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I am new to Node.js and am trying to build a node/express/mongoose server app with TypeScript.

Here is my app.ts file:

```
// lib/app.ts
import express from 'express';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { Routes } from './routes/crmRoutes';
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

class App {
  public app: express.Application;
  public routePrv: Routes = new Routes();
  public mongoUrl: string = 'mongodb://localhost/TodosDB';

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
    this.config();
    this.routePrv.routes(this.app);
    this.mongoSetup();
  }

  private mongoSetup(): void {
    mongoose.connect(this.mongoUrl, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
  }

  private config(): void {
    // support application/json type post data
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //support application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

However, when I try to compile my application, I get:

```
TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function
```

I've used up all my Google skill -- no luck.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: place the following in mongoSetup function and let me know what you'r getting ` mongoose.connect(this.mongoUrl, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log("data = ", data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });`

Comment: Log your mongoose just after loading the mongoose module.

Comment: I just copied your code and replace first line with `import * as express from 'express';` and it simple worked.

Comment: @AlokDeshwal -- thanks for your interest.  I can't log to the console because the code won't compile.  

Also, I replaced my import statement with what you had, and I get the same result.  Didn't change anything.

Comment: I made your change, did a `tsc ./lib/server.js` and that compiled.  Then it ran.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: By the way I really like the way you have designed your app class. :-)

Comment: I would like to know about the skeleton and file (MVC or other) organization of your project. Can you please share that? 
Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 31):

Replace:

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
```

With:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348146/5308115 - explanation

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me: replace

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
```

with

```
import mongoose = require("mongoose");
```

Answer (score 7):

if you have `"esModuleInterop": true,` in your tsconfig.json it forces you to import mongoose differently so change the above option or change the way you import mongoose

Answer (score 3):

A nice way is to import only the methods you need eg.

```js
import { connect } from 'mongoose';
```

Then in your class

```js
class App {
  private async mongoSetup(): Promise<void> {
    await connect(this.mongoUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone still get this error, try run it in server like **Express**
i learned it the hard way after spend almost 8 hours try every ways posible on Google

Comment: I was porting a Next app to React and had this silly problem haha

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in `Next.js 14`.i was invoking a Server Action function to execute a MongoDB query when I received this error: `TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function`.I later realized that the root of this issue was my omission of the `use server` directive in my code.

code(server-Action):

```
"use server"
//code here
```