# Specifying the MongoDB database connection statement in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have used a connection statement similar to this before, without issue.  But now I get a message TypeError:Mongoose.connect is not a function..

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB");
```

What on earth does this mean, and why does it want a function?

ps: I reinstalled Mongoose with npm but it made no difference.

Comment: It might be that you're trying to require mongoose client-side. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944769/why-am-i-getting-mongoose-connect-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-connect-wit

Comment: I guess...  the documentation is terrible.  If Express is a prerequisite they should say so.

I gave up on MongoDB and deleted it altogether...