# Run Quill editor with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, wysiwyg, quill

How can I get the Quill editor running in TypeScript?

I have a working example of the WYSIWYG-editor Quill from the [Quill site](https://quilljs.com/docs/quickstart/). The following code just has to be copied into an HTML file such as `example.html` and there will be a simple text editor example:

```
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```

Now I am trying to get this example running in TypeScript. The first thing would be to install `quill` and then install the types for TypeScript which should be `@types/quill`. Adding them in the `package.json` file and running `yarn` or `npm` loads the classes:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.31",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/react": "16.9.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "1.16.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
},
```

But when running the example with the `webpack-dev-server` I get an error. The command is:

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0 --config webpack.dev.config.js"
}
```

The error is:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/quill/node_modules/quill-delta/dist/Delta.d.ts:1:8 
    TS1259: Module '"/home/myuser/Documents/quill-example/node_modules/@types/quill/node_modules/fast-diff/diff"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag
```

I suppose there is something wrong with the `@types/quill` package, right? But what is exactly failing? What is the `esModuleInterop` doing exactly? Is there any fix to this error?

I could not find any Quill TypeScript example. It should be fairly easy to get it running in TypeScript, right?

Comment: [esModuleInterop info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file). Does it work if you set that flag to `true` in tsconfig?

Comment: @AlexWayne Ok, it did work. But I did not fully understand what `esModuleInterop` does. It influences the way that TypeScript handles the imports, right? It changes the asterisk-handling, right? But what is that for?

Answer (score 3):

Turn on `esModuleInterop`. You shouldn't have any problems from doing so.

---

Basically, there are two interfaces for import/export.

**The CommonJS way:** *(this came first)*

```
// a.js
module.exports = { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar' }
exports.baz = 'baz'

// b.js
const { foo, bar, baz } = require('./a.js')
```

Note that the export is always a single whole object. `module.exports` is the value that can be `require`'d.

**And the ES6 way:** *(the new and now recommended standard)*

```
// a.js
export default { foo, bar }
export const baz = 'baz'

// b.js
import baz, { foo, bar } from './a'
```

Note that there are now named exports and default exports. An ES6 module does *not* have a single exported value, but can export many values (one of which is the default value). These differences make translating between these syntaxes a bit complicated.

The `esModuleInterop` compiler option allows you to use ES6 style `import` with CommonJS style `module.exports`, and vice versa.

[Much deeper explanation here.](https://itnext.io/great-import-schism-typescript-confusion-around-imports-explained-d512fc6769c2)

Also, [this github issue](https://github.com/quilljs/delta/pull/34) seems to indicate that quill requires `esModuleInterop` to be turned on. Which is fine. It shouldn't cause you any problems.

> It sounds like we are going the path of relying on people to follow Typescript's recommendation for turning on `esModuleInterop` so will not keep this PR open.

So they discussed not requiring it, decided against it, and closed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example with typescript. you don't need to install any other library.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
 
const modules = {
  toolbar: [
    [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike", "blockquote"],
    [
      { list: "ordered" },
      { list: "bullet" },
      { indent: "-1" },
      { indent: "+1" },
    ],
    ["link", "code"],
    ["clean"],
  ],
};
 
const formats = [
  "header",
  "bold",
  "italic",
  "underline",
  "strike",
  "blockquote",
  "list",
  "bullet",
  "indent",
  "link",
  "code",
];
 
interface OnChangeHandler {
  (e: any): void;
}
 
type Props = {
  value: string;
  placeholder: string;
  onChange: OnChangeHandler;
};
 
const TextEditor: React.FC<Props> = ({ value, onChange, placeholder }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ReactQuill
        theme="snow"
        value={value || ""}
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    </>
  );
};
 
export default TextEditor;
```

Code credit should go to original author of [this article](https://www.adarshaacharya.com.np/blog/integrate-react-quill-with-antd-forms)