# Mocked `fs.createFileSync` and `fs.unlinkSync` are not getting called

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocking, jasmine

I have a function that does a lot of things, but among them is that it copies a file to a special directory, does something with it (calls something to interact with that file without using the `fs` module), and then deletes the copied file once finished.

```
import { copyFileSync, unlinkSync } from 'fs';

myOtherFunction(path: string) {
  ...
}

myIOFunction(somePath: string) {
  var copyPath = resolve('otherDir/file2.csv');
  copyFileSync(somePath, copyPath);
  try {
    myOtherFunction(copyPath);
  } finally {
    unlinkFileSync(copyPath);
  }
}

export myFunction() {
  ...
  myIOFunction(resolve('file1.csv));
}
```

Since only `myFunction()` is exported (it's the only thing that should be able to be directly interacted with), I have to unit test `myOtherFunction()` and `myIOFunction()` through it. Part of that is `copyFileSync` and `unlinkFileSync`.

My test looks something like this:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import myFunction from './myFile';

...

it("tests something involving input/output", () => {
  mockCopyFile = spyOn(fs, 'copyFileSync');
  mockUnlinkFile = spyOn(fs, 'unlinkSync');

  ...

  myFunction();

  expect(mockCopyFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(resolve('file1.csv'), resolve('otherDir/file2.csv'));
  expect(mockUnlinkFile).toHaveBeenCalled();

  ...
});
```

The test is failing with the errors that neither `mockCopyFile` nor `mockUnlinkFile` is called. The problem is that the corresponding functions *are* called - I've stepped through the test with a debugger, and they execute without issue. So the problem must be that the spies aren't properly attaching themselves.

I don't know how to *get* them to be called. I've tried doing `import * as fs from 'fs'` and `fs.copyFileSync()`/`fs.unlinkFileSync()` in the file being tested. I've tried putting the mocks in a `beforeAll()` function. Neither solution helps. I'm mocking several other, not immediately relevant, method calls in the same test spec, and they're all working exactly as intended; it's only this one that isn't, and I can't figure out why.

---

My `package.json` includes the following dependencies:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "tsc && jasmine",
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.7",
    "@types/pg": "^7.14.3",
    "copyfiles": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-ts": "^0.3.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "mock-fs": "^4.11.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.7.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "chokidar": "^3.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv-writer": "^1.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "murmurhash": "0.0.2",
    "pg": "^7.18.2",
    "pg-format": "^1.0.4",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

and my `jasmine.json` looks like so:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "dist",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

And `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "node_modules/@types/node"
    ],
  },
  "lib": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jasmine [`spyOn`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn) mocking function returns a [`Spy`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html) class object which does not represent any function call, but it has helper methods regarding mocking the function. You have to call `expect` directly to `fs.<function>` in order to check if it's called:

```ts
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import { myFunction } from '../src/myFunction';

describe('MyFunc', () => {
  it("tests something involving input/output", () => {
    spyOn(fs, 'copyFileSync');
    spyOn(fs, 'unlinkSync');

    myFunction();

    expect(fs.copyFileSync).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      path.resolve('file1.csv'),
      path.resolve('otherDir/file2.csv')
    );
    expect(fs.unlinkSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

You can test a simple repro example using this GitHub repo: https://github.com/clytras/fs-jasminte-ts-mocking

```sh
git clone https://github.com/clytras/fs-jasminte-ts-mocking.git
cd fs-jasminte-ts-mockin
npm i
npm run test
```

**UPDATE**

It appears that you're having  `esModuleInterop` set to `true` inside `tsconfig.json`. That means that when you `import * as fs from 'fs'` that won't keep a single instance of the `fs` object.

You can set `esModuleInterop` to `false` and have your tests passing with `toHaveBeenCalled` and `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, but that may break some other functionality of your project. You can read more about what `esModuleInterop` does here [Understanding esModuleInterop in tsconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file).

If you don't want to set `esModuleInterop` to `false`, then you have to import `fs` as in ES6 Javascript like this:

```js
import fs from 'fs'; // Use plain default import instead of * as
import path from 'path';
import { myFunction } from '../src/myFunction';

describe('MyFunc', () => {
  it("tests something involving input/output", () => {
    spyOn(fs, 'copyFileSync');
    spyOn(fs, 'unlinkSync');

    myFunction();

    expect(fs.copyFileSync).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      path.resolve('file1.csv'),
      path.resolve('otherDir/file2.csv')
    );
    expect(fs.unlinkSync).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I also noticed these things missing from your config files:

1. You have to use [`jasmine-console-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-console-reporter) if you don't:

   - `npm i -D jasmine-console-reporter`
   - Change `test` script inside `package.json` to be `"test": "tsc && jasmine --reporter=jasmine-console-reporter"`
2. Inside `jasmine.json`, add `ts-node/register/type-check.js` to helpers like:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "helpers": [
       "helpers/**/*.js",
       "../node_modules/ts-node/register/type-check.js"
     ],
   }
   ```

Now your tests should be passing.

Comment: I initially thought this worked, but upon further scrutiny, this didn't appear to work, regardless of whether the other function being tested invokes it as `copyFileSync` or `fs.copyFileSync`.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details on how it didn't work and maybe update your question with the errors you faced? This is about mocking `fs` functions. I'll provide an example with some debug logs to see how the functions are being called.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more detail I can provide - the error message is just `Expected spy unlinkSync to have been called once. It was called 0 times.` From using a debugger, the name `fs.copyFileSync` seems to be replaced by a spy immediately after I call `spyOn()`, but then as soon as I enter `myFunction()`, it's back to normal. I can actually see the file appearing and disappearing in my filesystem, which proves that the spy isn't sticking for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you please provide your `package.json` to see the versions using? It's working on my end with latest `jasmine@3.4.0` and it doesn't actually call any of the mocking functions. If we want to actually call the functions, we shall use [`callThrough`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/SpyStrategy.html) like `spyOn(fs, 'copyFileSync').and.callThrough()`. Did you try to clone and test the repo I posted? Does the repo code serve as a good reproduction of your case and if not, can you provide a minimal reproduction example? Because the github repo code literally has a function setup like yours.

Comment: Your repo code works on my machine; I don't know why mine isn't. My jasmine version is actually 3.5.0, along with `jasmine-core@3.5.0` and `jasmine-ts@0.3` and `@types/jasmine@3.5.10`. Does it matter if this file was imported/loaded (but nothing in it was called) by something else in the program (one of the other testing files, in a roundabout way) before this failing test was run?

Comment: No, it does not matter. I have duplicated the test and execute it before the one with the `fs` mocks and it passes everything (*fs functions got to execute before `spyOn`*). It seems I have a different setup, because my project does not use `jasmine-ts` at all, it uses `ts-node/register/type-check.js` inside `jasmine.json`. Can you please provide the contents of your `package.json` and `jasmine.json` so I can reproduce your exact project environment?

Comment: I've edited the contents of those files into my question.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to ask you to add the also very important `tsconfig.json` file. I have to check if you have `"esModuleInterop": true` inside. Please also add `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: I do have `esModuleInterop` set to true in tsconfig, though I've added that to my question as well.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You have to either set `esModuleInterop` to `false` inside `tsconfig.json`, or import `fs` as in JS like `import fs from 'fs'`. In any case, I added some remarks like that you have to use [`jasmine-console-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-console-reporter) and add `ts-node/register/type-check.js` to `helpers` array inside `jasmine.json` config file.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks so much.