# Airtable not defined after import

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, airtable

I am given this task to perform some stuff with data obtained from an AirTable API with NodeJS. I am using the AirTableJS node library with the DefinitelyTyped airtable definitions (I am using NestJS).

So, naturally, I do the following to import the necessary packages.

```
yarn add airtable @types/airtable
```

Then, in my repository that interacts with the AirTable API, I have the following.

```
import { User } from "../entities/user";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { LogService } from "src/log/services/log/log.service";
import { Base } from "airtable";


@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository {
    private readonly apiKey: string;
    private readonly baseId: string;

    constructor(@Inject(ConfigService) private readonly config: ConfigService, @Inject(LogService) private readonly log: LogService) {
        this.apiKey = this.config.get<string>('airtable.apiKey');
        this.baseId = this.config.get<string>('airtable.baseId');
    }

    async getUnmatchedUsers(): Promise<User[]> {

        const base: Base = new Airtable({apiKey: this.apiKey}).base(this.baseId);
        // other code here
     }
  }
```

But, when running it, I get the following error relating to the repository function:

```
ReferenceError: Airtable is not defined
```

Am I missing anything here or did I not import the Airtable package correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not defined because you haven't imported `Airtable`.

That's probably going to look like:

```
import Airtable, { Base } from "airtable";
```

Comment: I tried your solution. And, it doesn't seem to like me importing Airtable directly as it gices the error: ```Module "<path to airtable module in node_modules folder>" can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag```.

Comment: You should set `"esModuleInterop": true,` in your `tsconfig.json` file. Lots of npm modules require it to make default import work. And apparently airtable is one of them. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)

Comment: Alternatively, you could try `import * as Airtable from 'airtable'` or `const Airtable = require('airtable')`. But `esModuleInterop` really shouldn't cause you any trouble.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That works. I guess I should start setting esModuleInterop to true in all my projects to make stuff easier. :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently using Airtable in a Typescript project (tsconfig below) and the following allowed me to make api calls against my Airtable base.

Node v16.5.1
Typescript v4.7.4
Airtable v0.11.4

```
import Airtable from 'airtable';

Airtable.configure({
  endpointUrl: "https://api.airtable.com",
  apiKey: `${process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY}`,
});
const base = Airtable.base(AIRTABLE_BASE);

base('myTableKey')
  .select({ 
     fields: [
       'fieldA', 'fieldB'
     ]
  })
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Enable top-level await, and other modern ESM features.
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    // Enable node-style module resolution, for things like npm package imports.
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // Enable JSON imports.
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // Enable stricter transpilation for better output.
    "isolatedModules": true,
    // Add type definitions for our Vite runtime.
    "types": ["node","vite/client"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not answering the question that was asked

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `Airtable` class imported from anywhere, so Node and Tyepscript don't have any idea what it is. The closest you have is the `Base` type imported from the `airtable` pacakge. As their documentation isn't public, it's hard to say how to fix it.