# Typescript/babel import causing "_1.default is not a function"

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom from a typescript project compiled with webpack and babel.

The problem is that the typescript method call:

```js
import Panzoom from '@panzoom/panzoom';
Panzoom(document.querySelector("#pic"));
```

is transpiled to the following javascript:

```js
panzoom_1.default(document.querySelector("#pic"));
```

which then generates the following run-time error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: panzoom_1.default is not a function
```

If I debug the javascript then `panzoom_1` has the expected function signature and it has no `default` member.

This is some type of issue between the myriad different types of module, default exports and differences in how babel and typescript import them but I am totally lost. According to the docs, `panzoom` is a UMD module if that helps.

I have found a work-around to import in a different way and then cast it to any, but this is clearly insane right?:

```js
import * as Panzoom from '@panzoom/panzoom';
(<any>Panzoom)(document.querySelector("#pic"));
```

Here is the project configuration:

### test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
</head>
<body>
    <img src="pic.jpg" id="pic" />
</body>
<script src="dist/bundle.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

### test.ts

```js
import Panzoom from '@panzoom/panzoom';
Panzoom(document.querySelector("#pic"));
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": ".",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "traceResolution": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
    }
  }
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "grr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.7",
    "@panzoom/panzoom": "^4.1.0",
    "npm-update-all": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, options) => {

    var PROD = (options.mode === 'production');

    return {

        entry: [
            "@babel/polyfill",
            path.resolve(__dirname, "test.ts")
        ],

        output: {
            filename: "bundle.js",
            libraryTarget: "var"
        },

        resolve: {
            modules: [
                'node_modules'
            ],
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/, 
                    loaders: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options:
                                {
                                    compact: false,
                                    presets: [
                                        [
                                            "@babel/preset-env",
                                            {
                                                targets: "> 0.25%, not dead"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                }
                        },
                        'awesome-typescript-loader'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        devtool : false,
        optimization: {
            minimize: PROD
        }
    }
};
```

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/transform-async-to-generator"],
  "compact":false
}
```

Comment: Try `import Panzoom from '@panzoom/panzoom';`

Comment: ah sorry, I have corrected the question, that was indeed my original attempt.

Comment: It seems a babel configuration issue. Can you provide a stackblitz sample that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Eldar I don't think stackblitz supports webpack/babel - the necessary config files are in the question though

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have managed to fix it by adding `"esModuleInterop": true` to `tsconfig.json`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

> Emit __importStar and __importDefault helpers for runtime babel ecosystem compatibility and enable --allowSyntheticDefaultImports for typesystem compatibility.

Which means nothing to me, but a bit more information here:

[Understanding esModuleInterop in tsconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)

Comment: Try this at your own risk. Doing this in a nestjs project caused around 1000 complied js files to be generated. Needless to say, it was a nightmare.