# Debug Angular/Typescript in visual code appends '_1' to variable

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug an angular/typescript application in Visual Code. Let's say I run the following code

```js
try {
    ...
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Assume an error occurs, I will see in my console the error being logged for a normal execution. The issue I face is that if I run the same situation in debug mode ("Launch Chrome against localhost"). I will get:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined"

If I look at the 'Closure' section instead of the 'Local' section in the debug view. I have access to **`error_`** which indeed contains what normally gets logged in a normal execution.

Is there a way to view the error as **`error`** instead of **`error_1`** in debug mode for angular/typescript application?

I tried a suggestion from [Typescript/babel import causing "*_1.default is not a function*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61524130/) without any success.

[Error preview](https://ibb.co/NLmFhf1)

Comment: Why not use the watch section in the debug view instead Variables > Closure.  I would imagine you'll get the desired result for your "error" variable there

Comment: @John , I added [Error preview](https://ibb.co/NLmFhf1), as you can see I can't refer to 'error' in the watch section.

Comment: What angular version are you using? Where that thing happens? Inside component/service? I just setup latest app from boilerplate and can't reproduce what you have.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki, thing happens inside a component. The [following link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39625) provides useful information on this issue but it was not enough for me to fix this on my side .

My angular is based on 8.2.14.

Comment: How are you serving your frontend?  Did you run an npm run start through the terminal or is the code being built elsewhere?  Taking swings in the dark a little, but what does your launch.json file look like?

Comment: @John, "ng serve" for app launch, "Launch Chrome against localhost" for debug. (Angular CLI: 8.3.25, Node: 12.16.0, Angular: 8.2.14)

Comment: do you have both a launch and attach in your configuration array? something like this: "configurations": [{ "type": "pwa-chrome", "request": "launch", "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost", "url": "http://localhost:44378/",  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", "sourceMaps": true, }, { "name": "Attach Chrome", "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",  "url": "http://localhost:44378/", "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", "port": 9222,  "sourceMaps": true }]

Answer (score 3):

That thing happens when ECMAScript **target** version in ts config is below ES6.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
  }
}
```

If you can't increase it then there is no solution.

Perhaps this is caused by async/await function is being rewritten into __awaiter __generator form. It doesn't even use try catch concept here...

```js
 AppComponent.prototype.functionInComponent = function () {
        return Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__awaiter"])(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            var error_1;
            return Object(tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__generator"])(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0:
                        _a.trys.push([0, 1, , 3]);
                        ...
                    case 1:
                        error_1 = _a.sent();
                        ...
                        return [4 /*yield*/, asyncFunctionAfterConsoleLog];
                    case 2:
                        _a.sent();
                        return [3 /*break*/, 3];
                    case 3: return [2 /*return*/];
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't verify since I am in a context where I can't switch to ES6. I might try with a different project, will post an update if my situation changes.