# convert from now() using Date to Moment Timezone from America/Los_Angeles

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I would like to know if it is possible in typescript to convert `Date()` to `moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();`

I have tried

```
import { MomentTimezone }  from 'moment-timezone';
const moment : MomentTimezone = new MomentTimezone(Date(), "America/Los_Angeles");
```

but I have this error:

```
S2693: 'MomentTimezone' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

when doing

```
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";
let now = moment();
```

I have this error:

```
TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'typeof import("C:/Users/sandro/IdeaProjects/booking/node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts")' has no call signatures.
```

and

```
const moment: MomentTimezone = {date: Date(), timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles'};
```

but I got

```
TS2322: Type '{ date: string; timezone: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MomentTimezone'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'date' does not exist in type 'MomentTimezone'
```

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code—

```
import * as moment from "moment-timezone";
```

—is that in ES6, `import * as moment` syntax will always import `moment` as a *non-callable* module.

TypeScript used to be non-compliant, and let you call these imports anyway. But that won't fly in today's TS. Instead, we use the shorter:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone";
```

If you use that code then `moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format()` should work.

---

See also:

- [Understanding esModuleInterop in tsconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)