# Jquery in Typescript, AJAX: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I am trying to get AJAX working in typescript, so i've found a way how to add Jquery to Typescript.
I called these commands in VS code terminal:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install --save @types/jquery
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

After that i added these rows at the top of my main typescript file:

```
import jquery = require("jquery");
const $: JQueryStatic = jquery;
```

After I use `tsc scripts.ts` i get `scripts.js` file and move generated .js file to the project i get the error in the chrome browser: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1WAn.png

This is not react or angular project.

I don't know why, but it hard to find working answer on my question.. It seems like majority is using react or angular, so answers not fits to my problem.

All i want is to use AJAX calls via Typescript.

Comment: You do *not* need jQuery to use ajax. Just use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jQuery with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript)

Comment: @HereticMonkey i need it to be working in IE as well unfortunately.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what? Error is different from the url you provided.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Also as i told, i am NOT USING angular or react.

Comment: I know; only 2 of the 10 answers even mention Angular. The [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052431/215552) details exactly the steps needed to get jQuery working with TypeScript, with no mention of Angular or React.

Comment: IE supports [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), which is the basis of ajax. I mean, if you want to use jQuery for other things, rock on. Just seems a waste to pull in a largish library for a simple thing like ajax. There's also axios, which is a popular abstraction for ajax operations.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  XMLHttpRequest is not a good option, because of CORS policies.

Comment: *sigh* I've been doing "ajax" since before it was called ajax. [jQuery uses `XMLHttpRequest` behind the scenes](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js#L6), so any issues you think are unique to that technology will occur there too. CORS affects any HTTP connection you make from a browser to a server that implements CORS.

Answer (score 0):

First if you use typescript not sure why you would use require.
Second

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

You just need one `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev` you do not need your types in dependencies.

Hope it helps, if not maybe we can try something, some code example would help.

Edit:

Check [Krzysztof Grzybek solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348146/7028003)
His example is with moment js, but i think it can work for your problem. Try adding in your tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...   },
...
}
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code on this site, not only on an external site.

Comment: here is the error i get when using tsc command: "tsc scripts.ts
scripts.ts:3:8 - error TS1259: Module '"D:/cr/Scripts/node_modules/@types/jquery/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

3 import $ from 'jquery';
         ~

  node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:35:1
    35 export = jQuery;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag."

Comment: @HereticMonkey The code is nothing special
Just installing `npm install --save @types/jquery` and `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

`import $ from "jquery";
$.ajax({
  method: "get",
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
}).then(console.log);`
Anyway what I found is from [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file)
This example is with moment might help you with jquery
So in your tsconfig add(change) `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`  to true.

Comment: If you got inspiration from another answer on Stack Overflow, the proper thing to to is to give attribution, *in the answer*, along with the code, *in the answer*. See [answer].

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks.

To correct my answer.
Check [Krzysztof Grzybek solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348146/7028003) His example is with moment js, but i think it can work for your problem.

Try adding in your `tsconfig.json`
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  },
...
}`

Comment: I'm not having the problem. I'm trying to get you to [edit] your answer so that it follows the guidance established for answers, and doesn't get downvoted or deleted.