# TypeScript - "Import express" suddenly showing error after running "npm i @types/express -D"

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to add the below line of code in an index.ts file:
import express, { Application } from 'express';

But "from 'express'" was showing an error so I ran npm i @types/express -D which resolved the error on that side but created an error for "import express" now

The error I see is TS1259 but I cannot figure out what I should do to remove the error
Why would import express show an error when running @types/express and what can I do to solve it

I tried import express = require ('express') - but did not sort it

I can tell you as well that the folder node_modules is not visible in the project in visual studio. However is visible in the folder on my c drive

package.json is fine and shows correctly express

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320525/error-ts1259-module-node-modules-types-express-index-can-only-be-default

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
    import { Application } from 'express';
    import express = require('express');

    const app: Application = express();
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked. Appreciate it