# Why does Typescript prefer "import * from X"?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript.

I was running into an import issue.

`import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'`

Fails with..
`isEmpty.default is not a function`

I stumbled upon this..

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3542

And adding a..

`import * as isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'`

Does fix it.

But why?

Why does Typescript need imports like that? I'm trying to understand why this is necessary and what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Add `"esModuleInterop": true` to `compilerOptions` (tsconfig.json). More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file

Comment: Check out `esModuleInterop`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56238356/617159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you can only export the default function/class using the syntax in your first example.

Each file can have only one default export, which if you view the source will look like

```js
export default {function/class}
```

The source code can also be written to allow exports of non-default methods, for example

```js
export {function/class}
```

These exports don't have to be the filename.  The export themselves can be named different, i.e. exporting lodash is aliased as _.

If you want to pull out a non-default method from the library, and the method is named as an export in the library source code, you may use destructuring syntax if you are using es6

```js
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash'
```

In your second example, you are aliasing the package as isEmpty.  Ideally, using the destructuring method from the main lodash package to use a single method/function that is not a default export, or export the entire default and call the method. i.e.

```js
import _ from 'lodash'

_.isEmpty(var);
```

Comment: This presupposes a lot of things. For example, it presupposes that lodash has, as a default export, an object containing all of its named exports as properties.

Comment: True, you can only import functions that are named as exports.  Lodash does have a default export of '_'.  I'm not sure if isEmpty is importable, as this example was a hypothetical example of how destructuring works in es6.