# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined" in dotenv

Tags: node.js, typescript, dotenv

I'm trying to get access to my .env file via `dotenv` module, but I'm getting the below error

```
dotenv.config();
       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

I have `dotenv` installed in `node_modules` and `package.json`, my `.env` file is in the root folder, and I think everything is written correctly, but it doesn't work for some reason. I have tried reinstalling the module, didn't help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try the following :

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})
```

In Typescript

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I'm actually using typescript and importing modules using "import" keyword, is there a chance that the problem is somewhere here?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! My problem was with imports, switching from "import dotenv" to "import * as dotenv" did help

Answer (score 16):

Another way to fix this is to enable [esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) in Typescript [compiler options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file).

Open `tsconfig.json` and add this line:

```
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

so you can import it like this:

```
import hello from 'hello-world';
```

Comment: Asante sana. Thank you very much. This is why I was failing to import my packages using `import dotenv from 'dotenv'` and yet `const dotenv = require('dotenv')` was working. Very weird

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 const path = require('path')
 require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this worked for me:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: __dirname + '../.env' })
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

`require('dotenv').config()`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
const { dotenv } = require('dotenv')
```

to

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
```