# Unable to add ws library to angular project

Tags: angular, websocket

I am trying to add the `ws` npm library to my Angular Project but can't figure out how to do it correctly.

I have installed it using `npm install ws`. Now I am trying to import it in the `app.module.ts` file.

I've tried `import { WebSocket } from 'ws';` and in `imports` I've added `WebSocket`.

I've also tried other form of writing it and they all give me an error: `'WebSocket' can only be imported by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and using a default import.`

Removing the line `import { WebSocket } from 'ws';` and leaving `WebSocket` in the imports list seems to be okay. But I think that this is the wrong WebSocket because I don't see anything related to the `ws` library.

Is this alright or am I doing something wrong?

I was taking a look at `Sending and receiving text data` in this tutorial https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#sending-and-receiving-text-data for them it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not import your library into an Angular module, Angular module is a very specific architecture look at it here https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules.
You can use this library directly into a component or a service, in my opinion, you want to create a websocket.service.ts that will reference the library, and you will create some method around it.

Crawling quickly the web you can find an easy example here https://javascript-conference.com/blog/real-time-in-angular-a-journey-into-websocket-and-rxjs/ that demonstrates the concept.

Comment: Okay, I tried doing `import { WebSocket } from 'ws';` in a new `websocket.service.ts`. But I still get `'WebSocket' can only be imported by turning on the 'esModuleInterop' flag and using a default import.`.

Comment: Please do some research before posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238356/understanding-esmoduleinterop-in-tsconfig-file