# If 'React' is the default export from 'react', Why can't we use some other name instead of 'React'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I was searching for some answer to this question and found that while importing, 'React' doesn't need to be in {} as it is the default export and not a named export, Well that's correct, but I have also seen that while importing a default export, we could use any name for it on import. But in this case, we can use only the below import,

```
import React from 'react';
```

and not

```
import Somename from 'react';
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* import React that way, but if you're using JSX, you also need to update your configuration to tell the transpiler that you're using that the "builder" function is no longer `React.createElement`, but is instead `Somename.createElement`. (If you're using Babel, you do that with the [`pragma` directive](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx#pragma).) That's because, as it says in [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-represents-objects), this:

```
const element = (
  <h1 className="greeting">
    Hello, world!
  </h1>
);
```

Is transpiled to:

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  {className: 'greeting'},
  'Hello, world!'
);
```

...so `React` (or whatever name you change it to in the configuration) [must be in scope](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#react-must-be-in-scope). Other than that, it's fine.

Comment: Just to add onto this a bit, it's helpful to actually see what a transpiler is doing with JSX. [Here's an example](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAwiAtgB3AUzLAvDAFAShiwD4YAeAEwEsA3YgCTQBsmQyB6augKCA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Ctypescript&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.5&externalPlugins=).

Comment: Thank you @T.J Crowder and @ Nick, Those were very good explanations.